# Is it possible to read VIN from CAN data?

Tags: can-bus, obd-ii, vin

Will VIN information be available from CAN data? Does any ECUs are module broadcasts VIN information on CAN channel?

Answer (score 2):

You can read the VIN using [OBD-II mode 0x9 PID 0x2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs#Mode_09), other than that, it is mainly implementation dependant. Many vendors broadcast the VIN every second or so, many times from the BCM (body control module) but it varies from vendor to vendor, and may not be happening at all.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I will fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Any car that supports CAN has a method of getting the VIN, either through TP2.0 or UDS.  Is there a certain car that you're trying to communicate with?